# Enviar mensaje Whatsapp por medio de Wassenger fetch

Tags: php, javascript, fetch

Estoy haciendo un botón que, al ser clickeado, mande un mensaje por *Whatsapp*. Hice este *fetch* y estoy usando la API de *Wassenger*.

El tema es que no me está funcionando, no sé qué hacer, ya este es uno de los códigos que probé y el que esta más acertado.

Si saco el *fetch* y pongo el número en consola sí me lo muestra; si pongo el *fetch*, ni siquiera me tira el error del *catch*, pero en *POSTMAN* me funcionó ese mismo *fetch* y mandé un mensaje.

agradezco su ayuda!

```
                                <?php 
                                
                                
                                foreach ($link->query('SELECT * FROM users '.$filter) as $row){ ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['lastname'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['email'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['phone'] ?><button id="boton" onclick="llamarNum(<?php echo $row['phone'] ?>)">X</button></td>
                                    
                                    <td><?php echo $row['gender'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['address'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['fecha_de_nacimiento'] ?></td>

                                </tr>
                                <?php
                                    }
                                ?>
                                </table>
                                


                                <script>

                                
                                                                                                                    
                                function llamarNum (num) {
                                        console.log(num);
                                        var myHeaders = new Headers();
                                        myHeaders.append("token", "");
                                        myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

                                        var raw = JSON.stringify({ "phone": "${num}", "message": "Hello world! This is a test message." });

                                        var requestOptions = {
                                            method: 'POST',
                                            headers: myHeaders,
                                            body: raw,
                                            redirect: 'follow'
                                        };

                                        return fetch("", requestOptions)
                                            .then(response => response.text())
                                            .then(result => console.log(result))
                                            .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
                                        }
                                }
                                </script>
```

Comment: Cuando dices _el tema es que no me esta funcionando_ queda una amplia gama de posibilidades, ¿qué es exactamente lo que no funciona, obtienes algún mensaje de error, cuál es el mensaje?

Comment: si saco el fetch y consologueo el numero me lo muestra si pongo el fetch , ni siquiera me tira el error del catch, pero en postman me funciono ese micmo fetch y mande un mensaje

Comment: Agrega eso a la pregunta, por favor.

Comment: Por qué tantas "aaa.."?